What is the purpose of using `Any` as a type annotation?
I often see people annotate the type with Any, for example:
from typing import Any
def printtype(arg:Any) -> None:
   print(type(arg))

I searched online and people said that the purpose of using Any is to tell the type checker not to check its type. However, people use type annotations because that tells people and their type checkers about the type, and Any clearly doesn’t have the above effect. So what is the point? Why don’t we just leave the argument not annotated? For instance:
def printtype(arg) -> None:
   print(type(arg))

The type checker will not be able to check and everything works fine.

Any means "can be of any type". No annotation means "the writer didn't annotate this".

Is it true the only difference is that Any means “any input is considered” while no annotation means “the writer didn’t think of that” ?

They're probably just trying to satisfy a code review or linter requirement.

Type annotations are also used to communicate to human readers, not just automatic type checkers. It's a form of self-documentation.

Any usually suggests to me that the author is trying to comply with a linter rule that says that everything needs to be annotated, but they don't want to figure out how typing works and they've figured out that if they just stick Any on everything then CI won't complain at them.  In the example you give, the "correct" type annotation is object, IMO.
